# reading a number with upto 10 decimal point precision from txt file

Tags: matlab, double

I have numbers with upto 10 decimal points stored in a text file.

I read it in MATLAB and then do str2double on the number but i get only upto 4 decimal points. What should I do to get all the values after decimal.

Forexample:

```
str2double('-122.345464646')

ans =

  -122.3455
```

but I need the entire number
Thanks

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you only get *up to 4 decimal points* ?  You're not confusing Matlab's default display of floating-point numbers with how it stores them, are you ?  Investigate the `format` command.

Comment: Now that you have posted a code snippet I think that my initial suspicion is correct.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. yes you are correct. tnaks a lot

Comment: Following from High Performance Mark's comment, use `format long g` to display all of the digits

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:
Go to preference

1. List item
2. Go to Command Window Option
3. Then change the numeric format to long g

Alternatively, type `long g`  in command window